# Calculate working hours between exit date and 3 months before exit date bigquery sql

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate the total working hours between two dates in bigquery sql:
The dates being between **MAX(date)** and **DATE_SUB(MAX(date), interval 3 month)**.
In other words, I want to know the sum of working hours between the exit date and 3 months prior to the exit date.

**The current table is something like this:**

| id | date | hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 2020-10-01 | 12 |
| abc | 2020-12-07 | 4 |
| abc | 2020-12-12 | 12 |
| abc | 2020-12-25 | 6 |
| abc | 2021-01-07 | 9 |
| abc | 2021-02-04 | 7 |

**The ideal output is:**

| id | hours |
| --- | --- |
| abc | 38 |

I have multiple workers and workers have different working dates and hours.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by working hours.  Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: My apologies..I don't have a separate calendar table. You can just think of the working hours as how many hours the workers spent at work between 0 to 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a subquery here to calculate `exit_date` first:

```
with mytable as (
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2020-10-01' as date, 12 as hours union all
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2020-12-07' as date, 4 as hours union all
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2020-12-12' as date, 12 as hours union all
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2020-12-25' as date, 6 as hours union all
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2021-01-07' as date, 9 as hours union all
  select 'abc' as id, DATE '2021-02-04' as date, 7 as hours
)
select 
  id,
  sum(hours) as hours
from (
  select *, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as exit_date
  from mytable
)
where date >= DATE_SUB(exit_date, INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
group by id
```

[image]